# How to fix "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" error?

Tags: ssh

I cannot connect to my server via ssh using my computer, but I can connect to this server via my cell phone using termius app. I have checked `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` and my iptables, and I have alse searched google, it seems no answer fits this problem. I don't know how to solve it , here is `ssh -v  183.17.228.80` output

```
debug1: Connecting to 183.17.228.80 [183.17.228.80] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.=======================   
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0   
debug1: SELinux support disabled  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory    
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1    
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory   
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1      
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory   
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1   
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory   
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1   
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory   
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory   
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1   
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1   
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1  
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0  
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2   
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I can ping this server, here is telnet

```
telnet 183.17.228.29 22  
Trying 183.17.228.29...  
Connected to 183.17.228.29.  
Escape character is '^]'.                                                                 
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: Might want to check if you've got DenyHosts installed, DenyHosts has its own allow and deny hosts files.

Comment: are you sure that the software you're running on the PC is compatible with all the SSH encryption modes?

Comment: as I mentioned, I have checked hosts files, not for DenyHosts

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe the encrytion algorithm was different, but my client was putty....but I can ssh to the same server by terminus on IOS

Comment: From the path of the key files I suppose you are connecting as `root`. This is usually not enabled; look at your sshd configuration. `ssh -vvv`might give you more information.

Comment: And there seems to be no matching public key file in `/root/.ssh/`on the server.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer

Comment: the log message self explain about situation.  (ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer) that connection between local server and remote machine is not stable. mainly this occur due to packet drop. for troubleshoot you can ping remote machine and check sequence number as below:

Comment: the log message saying connection between local server and remote machine is unstable. mainly this occurs due to packet drop. you can ping remote machine and check icmp_seq=*  check network segment in between. 
[*@localhost ~]# ssh -l R1 192.168.56.111
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
[localhost ~]# ping 192.168.56.109
PING 192.168.56.109 (192.168.56.109) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.56.109: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=4.16 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.109: icmp_seq=6 ttl=255 time=11.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.109: icmp_seq=16 ttl=255 time=11.3 ms

Comment: My case was very simple, the machine i tried to connect hadn't ssh installed. :DDDD

Comment: client reboot worked for me

Answer (score 40):

Just **reboot your server** which you want to ssh. It worked for me, previously I was facing the same issue.

Comment: Could not find the root cause, but rebooting worked for me.

Comment: I ran into the same issue when ssh to my free server on AWS. It is caused by server is exhaust of memory. Reboot works.

Comment: @thistleknot, rebooting works for me and is an easy quick fix. Nothing horrible about that. Indeed I do not know what caused the problem, but rebooting did fix something.

Comment: If rebooting worked it probably not a configuration issue, but rather a resource issue. Maybe increasing the priority of ssh might have done the trick.

Comment: reboot server is a very very bad suggestion.

Answer (score 16):

That actually means that your IP is blacklisted by the server. Try to whitelist your IP address to be able to login.
You may take a look at the /etc/hosts list to see if your server's ip address have changed.

Comment: That is really not necessarily the case.

Comment: This seemed to be true for me. I found out that my Cloudways server had blacklisted my home IP, and I needed to manually whitelist it.

Comment: The problem disappeared after few hours , i don't know why but I wasn't need to do restart .

Comment: Thanks for the comment re: "Cloudways server had blacklisted my home IP" -- this had just happened to us - manually whitelisted and all good to go.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Right, I was not blacklisted after all. Although it sounded plausible at first, since I had many partly even wrong ssh tries with many public keys published at GitLab, I was not blacklisted in the end. This answer is a bit dangerous, I almost stopped the further work, lucky me that I did not. After many days, I do not know what was the problem in the end, perhaps I really had too many tries and had to wait. Or it was another thing, like a missing openssh install. I posted a [working guide how to use ssh to download a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66648529/11154841) here.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue but after restarting the sshd daemon I could connect to host.

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd && systemctl status sshd
```

This is only a temporary workaround until you increase the MaxAuthTries parameter.

Comment: restarting sshd had no effect in my case

Answer (score 7):

The way I solved the problem is I went to the host machine and ran a few commands.

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/sshd
sudo chmod 755 -R /var/run/sshd
sudo service ssh restart
```

I got connected to the machine after that.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like ssh daemon on the server is hung. Are you sure it is running? When you telnet to ssh, you have to see a signature. Something like:

```
telnet unixhow.com 22
Trying 35.228.26.20...
Connected to unixhow.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
```

What I see from your output is ssh daemon not responding on server side. I recommend to connect via IP-KVM (or in some other way) to the remote machine and restart sshd.

Comment: Valuable tip.  In my case I do not get anything after the "Escape character is " line.  Daemon does not appear to be hung though, as it accepts connections from localhost and from our vpn lan segment.

Comment: I know this is bit old, but do you have any suggestions on how to connect to the machine when sshd is hung?

Comment: Well, if SSHd is hung, obviously you can't SSH there. There are several options 1) Use IP-KVM (if you have one) 2) Restart machine (less preferable option is you have live traffic on the machine).

Answer (score 4):

The above error happen when you have limit of failed try to authenticate to the server and you have too many ssh keys on your client (more than value of MaxAuthTries)

What you can try is to increase the value of MaxAuthTries and restart sshd daemon. Or you can limit the number of keys in your `~/.ssh` directory and use subdirectories and `~/.ssh/config` file to define key per host/group of hosts

Comment: I have tried this, but failed, in fact I almost tried every method I can found on the internet, I guess the key was encryption negeotiation algorithm, but I don't how to fix it

Comment: what did you try? please update your question

Answer (score 4):

This could be because you do not have an openssh server running on your ubuntu. You can run the below command to check the status of your openssh server.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl status ssh
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-03-20 11:52:16 GMT; 5min ago
  Process: 1034 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1058 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 5.1M
      CPU: 122ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─1058 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Mar 20 11:52:15 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Mar 20 11:52:16 ubuntu sshd[1058]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 20 11:52:16 ubuntu sshd[1058]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 20 11:52:16 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 20 11:52:24 ubuntu sshd[1131]: Connection closed by 10.0.2.2 port 60566 [preauth]
Mar 20 11:53:59 ubuntu sshd[1135]: Accepted password for ubuntu from 10.0.2.2 port 60654 ssh2
Mar 20 11:53:59 ubuntu sshd[1135]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Mar 20 11:57:48 ubuntu sshd[1238]: Accepted password for ubuntu from 10.0.2.2 port 61124 ssh2
Mar 20 11:57:48 ubuntu sshd[1238]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
```

If the status is not `active (running)`, you might want to install and/or start the openssh-server. You can do so with the commands shown below.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution is add my local IP address to the `/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
sshd:192.168.10.88:allow
```

this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

There may be many reasons but one of most possible reason can be(in my case it was) **ssh / port 22 is not allowed by firewall**.

You can allow ssh connection by **User-interface** (some providers allow that) or If you have any alternative method to login (Ex. digitalocean provide a console button ) you can run below command

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow 22
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using my cellular hot spot to connect to the web, while I was working the console froze, and I couldn't connect any more `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

I tried to reset the SRV but it didn't help

Only when I change my network connection (to a hotspot on a different cellular) I could connect again.

NOTE: I can still use the old connection to connect to SRVs on a different AWS, strange...

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue, proceed as follows:

1. Reboot your server from server online terminal.

If this does not work,

2. Edit the file `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts`
3. Delete any content inside this file, when it will reconnect to any servers you ssh then you must re-accept connections.

Comment: -1 for the complete deletion of `known_hosts`. It would be better to edit this particular host in question (although I doubt that will help here).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same thing happen, and needed to ssh -v 'ip addr' and then i saw that i needed to accept the certificate.
Also may be an ACL or route rule blocking putty: example -

Putty client has 10.x.x.x addr with firewalls blocking enterprise network from talking to DMZ hosts, but your cell phone at 58.x.x.x whatever public ip address can talk to the dmz host youre trying to reach.

so I'd look at the ssh -v info when you try to connect again, see if you can glean any info, and then check if there are rules keeping you from getting to your server at a firewall or router level, not in a denyhosts file on the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

Create an new ssh key pair for user authentication. [SSH Keys and Public Key Authentication guide](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/)

Just follow the guide.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that sshd in installed and running of the server.
2. Make sure that the daemon is installed and started.You must be able to 'man sshd'. I think that package  it is in is open-ssl, and you will need to start the daemon ( and stop it when you don't need it.).

Comment: of course I have installed sshd, as I mentioned, I can ssh to the same server by terminus on iphone...but putty failed

Answer (score 0):

After many days, I do not know what was the problem in the end, perhaps I really had too many tries and had to wait. Or it was another thing, like a missing openssh installation. I posted a [working guide how to use ssh to download a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66648529/11154841) here, with the core of it as follows:

```
# first image only to download the git repo
FROM alpine as MY_TMP_GIT_IMAGE

RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh &&  chmod 700 /root/.ssh
COPY /.ssh/id_ed25519 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519

RUN apk -yqq add --no-cache openssh-client && ssh-keyscan -t ed25519 -H gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN git clone git@gitlab.com:GITLAB_USERNAME/test.git
RUN rm -r /root/.ssh


# Start of the second image
FROM MY_BASE_IMAGE
COPY --from=MY_TMP_GIT_IMAGE /MY_GIT_REPO ./MY_GIT_REPO
```