# ssh_exchange_identification — read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: server, ssh, xubuntu, openssh

I was playing the "Overthewire Bandit" war game and when I try to login to level 20 I am getting the error

`ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @VarunHedge, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/918667/how-to-fix-ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer-error

Comment: I ran some of the commands which are mentioned , it didn't solve

Comment: How about [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-connection-reset-by-peer-ssh-error#:~:text=The%20%E2%80%9Cssh_exchange_identification%3A%20read%3A%20Connection%20reset%20by%20peer%E2%80%9D%20error,temporary%20outage%20or%20connectivity%20issue.) website? Did that help?